# Find parent view by id

Tags: java, android

I have a little complex layout and I add a tag to the SwitchLayout of this view.

There is an ImageButton inside this view.
Here is a little map to this button:

LinearLayout -> SwitchLayout -> RelativeLayout -> RelativeLayout -> ImageButton

At some point I want to get the tag attached to the SwitchLayout, but all I have is the reference to the ImageButton.

I've tried to look for an ID, but it seems that android is searching downwards only, so

```
imageButton.findViewById(R.id.switchLayout);
```

doesn't work.

It also looks like I can't get the assigned tag directly from the ImageButton.

This code:

```
imageButton.getTag()
```

returns `null`

The only one workaround I found is here, but it is ugly:

```
ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher)imageButton.getParent().getParent().getParent();
viewSwitcher.getTag();
```

I would like to make the coupling as week as possible, so I'm wondering if there is either a way to assign the Tag to the viewSwitcher and all of it's children,

Or findViewById among parent views.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not just keep the reference of switch layout?

```
// In activity
switchLayout = findViewById(R.id.switchLayout);
imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

If your method is still in the activity, you can directly access switchLayout, if not, you can set switchLayout to imageButton tag and read it later,

```
imageButton.setTag(switchLayout);
```

or if you really need to do this, you can do it recursively,

```
public ViewParent findParentRecursively(View view, int targetId) {
    if (view.getId() == targetId) {
        return (ViewParent)view;
    }
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    if (parent == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return findParentRecursively(parent, targetId);
}
```

Comment: That's the one! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

declare and define a reference to the swtichlayout and get the tag directly. why do u want to get the tag of switchlayout using the imagebutton.

Comment: I have a specific object of a class assigned to the switchlayout. When somebody presses my ImageButton I want to invoke a specific method from that object.

Answer (score 1):

I use this Kotlin code in my apps:

```
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.IdRes

fun <T : View> View.findParentViewById(@IdRes viewId: Int): T? {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return when (this.id) {
        viewId -> this as? T
        else -> (parent as? View)?.findParentViewById<T>(viewId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the views (controls) in android are of type `View`, so you can use `getId()` to find the id. 
You can use the following snippet

```
int parentId = ((View) arg0.getParent()).getId();
```

Comment: you mean the imageButton? then this code will give me the id of the RelativeLayout and this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extension function version of the accepted answer:

```kotlin
fun View.findParentById(@IdRes id: Int): ViewGroup? {
    if (this.id == id) return this as? ViewGroup
    return (parent as? View)?.findParentById(id)
}
```